# jxls - multiple row (list) binding doesn't work

Tags: java, excel, jxls

I'm trying to create excel form using jxls library.

my excel template is :

[image]

when I just add one map to list and bind it, it works.
my code is simply :

```
List<Map<String,Object>> sss = new ArrayList();

HashMap<String,Object> sm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
sm.put("name1", "AtestName");
sm.put("name2", "AtestName2");
sm.put("name3", "AtestName3");
sss.add(sm);

Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
model.put("sData", sss);
....  XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer(); .....
```

[image: success_result]

but when I add multiple map to list and bind it, it fails throwing exception.
I heard jxls library automatically recognize list.
What am I doing worng?

```
List<Map<String,Object>> sss = new ArrayList();
HashMap<String,Object> sm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
sm.put("name1", "AtestName");
sm.put("name2", "AtestName2");
sm.put("name3", "AtestName3");
sss.add(sm);

HashMap<String,Object> sm2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
sm.put("name1", "BtestName");
sm.put("name2", "BtestName2");
sm.put("name3", "BtestName3");
sss.add(sm2);

HashMap<String,Object> sm3 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
sm.put("name1", "CtestName");
sm.put("name2", "CtestName2");
sm.put("name3", "CtestName3");
sss.add(sm3);

Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String,Object>();
model.put("sData", sss);
....  XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer(); .....




[ 06:15:10] DEBUG - AbstractExcelView.renderMergedOutputModel(140) | Created Excel Workbook from scratch
[ 06:15:10] DEBUG - SheetTransformer.transformSheet(72) | Processing sheet: Sheet1
[ 06:15:10] DEBUG - CollectionRowTransformer.processRowCollections(96) | ----collection-property--------->sData
, 2016 6:15:10 오후 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/SheetConditionalFormatting;
    at net.sf.jxls.util.Util.copyConditionalFormat(Util.java:642)
    at net.sf.jxls.util.Util.copyCell(Util.java:569)
    at net.sf.jxls.util.Util.duplicateStyle(Util.java:411)
    at net.sf.jxls.util.Util.duplicateRow(Util.java:244)
    at net.sf.jxls.controller.SheetTransformationControllerImpl.duplicateRow(SheetTransformationControllerImpl.java:140)
    at net.sf.jxls.transformer.CollectionRowTransformer.processRowCollections(CollectionRowTransformer.java:106)
    at net.sf.jxls.transformer.CollectionRowTransformer.transform(CollectionRowTransformer.java:66)
    at net.sf.jxls.transformer.SheetTransformer.transformSheet(SheetTransformer.java:88)
    at net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer.transformWorkbook(XLSTransformer.java:248)
    at net.sf.jxls.transformer.XLSTransformer.transformXLS(XLSTransformer.java:221)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting` most likely means that you have an issue with POI versions.

So please check the Apache POI version you do use and if it supports `Sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting()` method

Comment: I checked POI 3.7 that I'm using. There is no the method. I chagned it to 3.9 and it's solved. Thanks Mr Vysochyn :)